# Current Item blank...can not recreate in SharePoint 2013 Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I have a List using a customized Workflow created in SharePoint Designer 2013.

One of the conditions is `Current Item: Not Equal to Yes`.

I am reusing WF in another site collection, however, I'm not able to create recreate this.

I can't leave the CUrrent Item blank which the drop-down lists the fields of the List.  When I click ok, it wouldn't allow me to save the condition.

Is there a way to create this condition without using a Field Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a way to create this condition without using a Field Name?**
No, It's impossible to create a condition from the current item without using a `field from source`.

[image]

**To investigate your issue in your old workflow, try to**

- Click on `Current Item:` to check from where it built the condition.
- Click on the Check errors button to show if there is an error in your old workflow.
- Make sure that the condition is not written manually as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hello Mohamed El-Qassas, the second image is exactly what the old one looks like.  So someone probably wrote this condition manually?  Is there any reason why or purpose for this method?

Comment: exactly, I wrote it manually and In my opinion, there is no purpose for this method, even if he tried to do condition outside the current item he should use a variable, but in this case, it will show *variable: current item* otherwise you can't use the current item without specifying the field name! hope it helps!

Comment: Great, I’ll mark you response as a answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome :)